# I can't see the benefits of versioning my web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, software-design

Why should I versioning my web api? I can't really see why I should do this.

I have read this article: https://vladsukhachev.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/web-api-versioning-in-real-world-applications/

In the article, the author creates a method called GetV1_0 for version 1. Then hebasically creates the same method again, but renames the method to GetV1_1 for version 1.1. Why? Why would I do this? Why not just change the first one without any versioning?

Anyone who can come some benefits why I should do like this, instead of just update the method if anything new should be added?

Comment: If a customer complains about your software, wouldn´t it be nice if you knew which version of your program he is running? Maybe the problem is already solved in your current developing-environment.

Comment: you don't want your clients to be forced to change theire clientsoftware everytime u change anything. So if your customers want to access new functions they got to change THEIRE code. if not - they are good to go with the existing one. **!** Versioning still should be done on controller level rather than methodlevel (`api/v1/getdata` vs. `api/getdata_v1`) **!**

Comment: Ok, so if you are API is being used by a customer and you suddenly changed something and published it then the customer is forced do those changes in his application too, that is where versioning helps a lot, your customer can use v1 and can move v2 without any hurry or may not move at all till the you have not declared a depreciation date of your old version.

Comment: No author creates different method which returns different DTO with different data fields.

Comment: you might as well have titled this: "What are the benefits to Web API versioning?" .. and though that would make for a good article (and they do exist) .. I agree, it is a broad topic, on-going discussion Q&A post.. and doesn't really have a problem statement.  Didn't SO come up with Articles feature a couple years back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's explained in the first paragraph of the [article](https://vladsukhachev.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/web-api-versioning-in-real-world-applications/) you linked to:

> Customers who use your API expect it to not change. Otherwise their
>   code may fail due to changed contract or behavior. But requirements
>   will change and we need to figure out a way to evolve API without
>   breaking existing clients. So every time when a breaking API change
>   occurs you need to release a new version of API. That does not mean
>   you need to support all versions forever. But you need to get rid of
>   old versions of API with some care so customers have an idea how to
>   move to a newer version of API.

Imagine a scenario where you write an API to be used by software written by other people. They can only start developing a new version of their software after the new version of your API has been released. But they don't want their existing application to break while they adapt to your new API.

*I suppose you could release a test version which others can test against and then only release once everyone has migrated, but this tactic does not scale well with many users.*

By versioning your API calls, the existing application of these other people can continue running while they develop a new version that works on the new version of your API.

Comment: Did not see It like that. I just got stucked when I saw the identical code. It looked bloated to me when he had 2 version of basically the same code of method. And let's say a third version of the method is developed.. But now I see the benefits. Thank you.